# ruby on rails: search through associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, associations, where-clause

I have little understanding problem:

I have `Channel` and `Lecturer`, where a `Channel` `:has_and_belongs_to_many :lecturers`.

I want to get all Channels where Lecturer.id is lect.id.

```
2.3.0 :235 >   Channel.where(:lecturers => { :id => 2 })
  Channel Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "channels".* FROM "channels"  WHERE "lecturers"."id" = 2
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: lecturers.id: SELECT "channels".* FROM "channels"  WHERE "lecturers"."id" = 2
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: lecturers.id: SELECT "channels".* FROM "channels"  WHERE "lecturers"."id" = 2
```

This does not work and I feel like I don't understand the core concept, since I can do

```
2.3.0 :231 > Channel.first.lecturer  
=> #<Lecturer id: 2, name: "Albert Einstein">
```

What am I missing?

Comment: "This does not work" - *how*? What *does* happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to join the tables to do this query.  See [the docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables)

```
Channel.joins(:lecturer).where(lecturers: {id: lect.id})
```

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it!

Answer (score 0):

what worked on my end was using left_outer_joins instead of joins for a belongs_to association. Example below.

```
scope :search, lambda { |search|
                    left_outer_joins(:city)
                   .where('lower(events.name) LIKE :search OR lower(cities.name) LIKE :search',
                          search: "%#{search.downcase}%")
               }
```